# Cylinders compression

Tags: engine, chevrolet, equinox

Hello I was doing a compression test on a2019 Chevy equinox thought it was da starter and battery cause the car was slowly turning over changed the spark plugs.scanned it and got a code of p0336,p0300,p050d

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you clear the codes and restart the car, do the codes come back?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.